# Blender 3.0 is not using my GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

When I render a scene in blender 3.0 using cycles, it uses only my CPU.

I have already done *Edit > Preferences > System > Cycles Render Devices*, and *Render Properties > Device > GPU Compute*. I've also tried a clean reinstall of the latest Nvidia driver (I tried the game ready *and* studio drivers).

I even reseated my GPU. I also know that the issue is not with task-manager, the 0-8% GPU and 100% CPU usage I'm seeing is accurate. I have this problem in both CUDA and OptiX. My GPU is being used by every other program I have that's supposed to use it so it's not a problem with the GPU itself.

I have a 3060ti.

Comment: You're looking at the Task Manager section for CUDA usage?

Comment: No. I know task manager doesn't show GPU usage for CUDA correctly, I've used just about every system monitor available and it's always 100% CPU and about 0-8% GPU. Plus like I said I have this problem in OptiX too.

Comment: I've had this problem in one file I was carrying across different PCs.  I had to go and select CPU for everything and restart and then I was able to select and utilize GPU.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't fix anything

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to fixed it by selecting "Optix" in the Denoiser option under Render Properties.

[image]